# Getting a ajax pagination values in Drupal custom module?

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

I have slideshow page comes from view

Page URL: http://localhost.com/entertainment/word

In this page i have slideshow that have prev and next button..

When i press next button, it calls views ajax and goes to next slide by append ?page=2 then URL becomes "http://localhost.com/entertainment/word?page=2" **without page refresh** .

After every ajax call i need to get the appended value like page="2" in custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's ajax call, I guess you should get the page value using JS.

```
    document.URL.split("page=")[1]
```

Comment: can't i get the value in .module file?? because with that value i need to implement functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the active page within a module (server-side), you can make use of the [`pager_find_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_find_page/7) function.

This will return an integer of the active page based on the `page` querystring parameter.

- http://localhost.com/entertainment/word would return 0
- http://localhost.com/entertainment/word?page=2 would return 2
- etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I have done with Sessions.

Got nid in the view page and assigned to seesion variable.

get that session variable in .module file.